# How can I calculate a metric ratio in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to show a metric based on a ratio of other two metrics. Scripted Fields aren't a solution, because they calculate document by document, and I need the ratio between two aggregations.

Is there any way?